# Trouble understanding re.findall() behavior

Tags: python, regex

I'm having some trouble understanding the behavior of [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall). Quoting from the documentation:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

Based on this, I would expect the following line

```
re.findall(f"(a)|(b)|(c)","c")
```

to produce the result

```
[(c)]
```

However, it produces the result

```
[('', '', 'c')]
```

I don't understand why the two empty strings are included, since I don't see an empty match anywhere.

Comment: The last line says it all - "If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result." So there are a total of 3 groups in your pattern, out of which two are empty.

Comment: The first and second groups `(a)` and `(b)` matched nothing, so you get an empty string for the first two groups, and `'c'` for the third one, as it is supposed to happen according to the documentation.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I thought an empty string would only be returned if it was actually matched, not if nothing was matched at all, at least that's how I interpreted the documentation. Your explanation makes more sense with the observed behavior though, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of having three capturing groups:

```
import re

print(re.findall(r"(a)|(b)|(c)","d"))
print(re.findall(f"(a)|(b)|(c)","c"))
print(re.findall(r"(?:a)|(?:b)|(?:c)","c"))
print(re.findall(f"(?:a)|(b)|(c)","c"))
print(re.findall(f"(?:a|b|c)","c"))
print(re.findall(r"a|b|c","c"))
```

#### Output

```
[]
[('', '', 'c')]
['c']
[('', 'c')]
['c']
['c']
```